# Asterisk play background sound file while connecting and overdialing

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to find a work-around for `asterisk` dialing on `motif` (google Voice) , which has recently become unreliable.

I am now using something like this which makes calls more reliable but a connection delay:

```
Motif/gusernamegmailcom/1xxxxxxxxxx@voice.google.com,300,**m**D(wwwwww2w$OUTNUM$#www)
```

The only issue I have is I do not want to play music rather a sound file in background. This is through the time it is connecting, connected and tones are over-dialed. Once the `#` is dialed we must immediately hear the Google Lady saying `"this is a free call"`.

I have tried several variations and can not seem to get it right, maybe someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can play any file as moh

You also have option to play as moh output of any script(see moh documntation type custom)

There is no option play file. You can write your own code for that or use app_spy/conference.